# How to map prop passed to client component in NEXT 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to the next 13 APP directory and it works when I map in the server component like this:

```
const Tasks = async () => {
  const { tasks } = await getAllTasks()
  
  return (
    <section>
      <ul className="flex flex-col mx-3">
        {tasks?.map(({_id, title, body}: TaskProps) => (
          <Task key={_id} id={_id} title={title} body={body} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Tasks
```

Though when I try to extract this code into a client component (so that I can useEffect), I'm unable to map the passed 'tasks' prop

```
 "use client"
//my imports here

export default function TaskList (tasks) {
      return (
          <ul>
            {tasks.map((task) => (
              <Task key={_id} id={_id} title={title} body={body} />
            ))}
          </ul>
      )
    }
```

Task.tsx:

```
  export default function Task({ id, title, body }: TaskProps) {
  async function deleteTask() {
    await removeTask(title);
  }
  return (
    <li key={id}>
      <div className="flex justify-between" >
        <h1 className='font-bold'>{title}</h1>
        <span 
          className="material-icons hover:cursor-pointer text-skin-dark" 
          onClick={deleteTask}
        >delete</span>
      </div>
      <a className="mr-12" >{body}</a>
    </li>
  );
}
```

I've tried a conditional return for the tasks prop 'tasks && ( JSX )'
Also tried putting the list item tags around Task, inside Tasks

Appreciate any assistance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you passing `tasks` into your client component from your server component? It also looks like you might have forgotten to destructure your client component's props. You wrote

```
"use client";
//my imports here

export default function TaskList(tasks) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <Task key={_id} id={_id} title={title} body={body} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

but `tasks` should be a property on an object, like this:

```
"use client";
//my imports here

export default function TaskList({ tasks }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <Task key={_id} id={_id} title={title} body={body} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: I was forgetting to destructure within the tasks. It's always the simple errors haha! thank you

Comment: Indeed it is! You got it :)